# How to make uppercase roman letters upright in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, french

Using `\setupmathematics[ucgreek=normal]`, one can force uppercase Greek letter to be upright.
How to do the same with Latin letters? The words `ucroman` and `uclatin` do not appear on the ConTeXt wiki.

Comment: Use `\setupmathematics[default=normal]` to get upright latin letters as default.

Comment: The problem is that it also affects lowercase letters

Answer (score 1):

There is something called `ucletters` that is mentioned in the code close to `ucgreek`, but I could not change anything with it. Maybe one could ask on the list, or wait for someone with better knowledge than me.

One could replace with `\definefontfallback` (I hope this is a somewhat modern version, it seems to work at least):

```
\definefontfallback [myfallback] [file:texgyre-termes-math-regular.otf][uppercasenormal][offset=uppercaseitalic,force=yes]

\starttypescript [math] [myfont]
  \loadfontgoodies[texgyre]
  \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [file:texgyre-termes-math-regular.otf] [features=math\mathsizesuffix,fallbacks=myfallback]
\stoptypescript

\definetypeface [myfont] [rm] [serif] [termes] [default]
\definetypeface [myfont] [mm] [math]  [myfont] [default]

\setupbodyfont[myfont]

\startTEXpage[offset=3bp]

Math in text: $ABC abc$

Displayed math:
\startformula
f_A\neq f_B
\stopformula

\stopTEXpage
```

[image: Result with uppright upper case letters]